# Debugging a Node lambda in Localstack

Tags: node.js, lambda, localstack

https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Would like to be able to get step debugging working from my IDE on a node lambda running in localstack.  There seems to be support for JVM debugging via `LAMBDA_JAVA_OPTS` but can't see anything for Node.

How do I open a debug port for a Node app in localstack?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the VS Code debugger to attach to nodejs by doing this.
In docker-compose.yml for localstack (notice no quotes):

```
environment:
  - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse
  - LAMBDA_DOCKER_FLAGS=-p 9229:9229
  - LAMBDA_REMOVE_CONTAINERS=false
```

Create the lambda with this:

```
--environment Variables="{NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229'}"
```

If you run `docker ps` you will see the lambda container running.

```
d5788b1928ca   mlupin/docker-lambda:nodejs16.x   "/var/rapid/init --b…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes             0.0.0.0:9229->9229/tcp
```